# Determining isomorphism for multiple graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

[image]

Question: Determine the pairs of isomorphic graphs.

My answer so far: The first three graphs have 8 vertices with 3 degree. The last one has 2 vertices with 4 degree so I automatically eliminated that one. Then I determined the cycle length for each of the 4 possible graphs and found that they all had the same cycle length.. so now, it has passed 4 of my tests: edges, vertices, degrees, cycle length, would this suffice in saying that all 4 are isomorphic to each other?

Comment: You really should find maps between the vertices that preserve all incidences.

Comment: By "first three" did you men "first four"? By "cycle length" did you mean "maximum cycle length"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only foolproof way to show that two graphs *are* isomorphic is to show an actual isomorphism between them.

If you try that for your four graphs you will find that this is possible for some of the pairs -- but not for others.

*Hint:* At least one of the four first graphs contains an edge that is part of exactly one 4-cycle. At least one other graph does not have such an edge.

*Alternative hint:* The second graph is obviously bipartite. The fourth graph is *not* bipartite, because it contains a cycle of length 5.

Comment: Don't really understand, I find 4 cycle length for all of them? First graph: 1,4,8,5,1 - 4, Second graph: 9, 16,10,15,9 - 4, Third: 17,24,19,18,17 - 4, Fourth: 25, 32, 31, 26, 25 - 4

Comment: @RobertMiller: For example, the 1-4 edge does not have the property I spoke about: It is part of _two different_ length-4 cycles, namely 1-4-8-5-1 and 1-4-3-2-1. So it is not part of _exactly one_ length-4 cycle.

Comment: My friend forgive me but I am not understanding. Wouldn't 1-4-3-2-1 be exactly a length of 4? So what you are telling me is that Graph 1 can also be eliminated because it does not have the same length as the others? Look at graph 3 we can do 17-22-23-24-17, so not exactly one length 4 cycle?

Comment: @RobertMiller: Yes, 1-4-3-2-1 has length 4, but 1-4-8-5-1 _also_ has length 4, so the number of length-4 cycles that contain 1-4 is (at least) **two**. On the other hand, there is **only one** length-4 cycle that contains 25-28, namely 25-28-29-32-25. This shows that you cannot have an isomorphism that maps 1 to 25 and 4 to 28.

Comment: For Graph 2 cant I also do 9-16-12-13-9 and another 9-16-10-15-9. Also adding onto your alt hint: 25-26-31-32-25, thats cycle length 4 not 5?

Comment: @RobertMiller: Yes, 25-26-31-32-25 is a cycle of length 4. But the graph _also_ contains several cycles of length 5.

Comment: This is so confusing. I can't find a single cycle length 5, I didn't know that a graph could have more than one cycle.... So for from this conversation I have that Graph 1 has two 4 length cycles, Graph 2 is bipartile, Graph 3 ??? Graph 4 ???, not really understanding what to match with what

Comment: @RobertMiller: Try 25-28-27-31-32-25. There are _many_ different cycles in each of the graphs.

Comment: In graph 4, couldn't I map 1 to 25 and 4 to 32 and have two 4 length cycles?

Comment: @RobertMiller: Yes, 25-32 is in two different length-4 cycles. But if you are to have an isomorphism, _something_ would need to map to the 25-28 edge. What could that be?

Comment: 2 to 28, 3 to 29

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72079/discussion-between-robert-miller-and-henning-makholm).